# Better ways to deal with React properties toString or similar method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-effect

I'm fixing up some react components as a beginner myself, in this particular piece there is an info column that displays contact links and info for a business.

What I'm trying to do after the return statement where elements render is to hide the column if the length for each value passed from the API. Hence why I try the .length method.

The main issue was the properties were giving me TypeErrors when I tried to use a toString method on something like business.email.toString.
To be exact, the error was:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

I opted for another method that worked before this one, applying something similar to the following in all 4 properties:

```
  business.email = new String(business.email).valueOf();
```

However, I realize using objects this way may impact performance. The current solution does not use that String object method, but may turn into an error if one of these properties is null. I realize perhaps this is related to React State and its hooks or maybe I'm not using props the right way since I'm still on the learning path to using them.

I appreciate any and all input for a better way to do this!

Here's the current code section.

```
//Imports


interface Props {
  top?: boolean;
}

const BusinessDescription: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const locBusiness: BusinessModel = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.locationsReducer.business
  );
  const [business, setBusiness] = useState<any>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!locBusiness || !locBusiness.id) return;
    BusinessHomepageAPI.getHomepage(locBusiness.id).then((response) => {
      setBusiness(response.data);
    });
  }, [locBusiness]);

  function addhttp(url: string) {
    ...
    return url;
  }

  business.web_page = addhttp('' + business.web_page);
  business.phone_number = '' + business.phone_number;
  business.whatsapp_number = ''+ business.whatsapp_number;
  business.email = ''+ business.email;

  return (
    <Col className={props.top ? style._contactUs1 : style._contactUs2}>
      {business.phone_number.length > 4 ||
      business.whatsapp_number.length > 4 ||
      business.email.length > 4 ||
      business.web_page.length > 10 ? (
        <span className={`${style.__container} ${style.__title}`}>
          <Translate id="BusinessInfo.ContactUs" />
        </span>
      ) : null}
    ...
    //rest of render and visual elements
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? i.e. `business.email?.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

This error is thrown when you attempt to call a method or property on something that is currently undefined.

Depending on where it is being used you could use an `if` statement, ternary statement or optional chaining to get around this problem.

**if Statement**

```
// Create variable to store value (initialise with preferred default).
let email = undefined;

// Check if property is 'truthy', which in this case should mean it has a value.
if (business.email) {

    // Use 'toString()' on a value you know not to be 'undefined'.
    email = business.email.toString();
}
```

**Ternary Statement**

```
// Same as an if statement above but more compact.
// May be better or worse depending on coding principles / standards
const email = business.email ?      // The condition (check property is turthy)
    business.email.toString() :     // If the condition is true (use 'toString()')
    undefined;                      // If the condition is false (use default)

// Can be written on a single line
const anotherEmail = business.email ? business.email.toString() : undefined;
```

**Optional Chaining**

```
// Shorter / neater than the other two options.
// This does not give you control to change the default value if 
// 'business.email' is not defined.
const email = business.email?.toString();

// This can essentially be written as a ternary statement
const email = busness.email !== null && business.email !== undefined ? 
    business.email.toString() : 
    undefined;

// To change the default value you can assigned when 'business.email' 
// is undefined you can group with a null-coalescing operator.
const email = business.email?.toString() ?? 'default@email.com';
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the stellar answer! I'll be looking into which implementation will be best suited, though the ternary statement is what I'm thinking will work best in this case.